# What is the quick save slot used for?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Whenever I save I notice there's an unused "Quick Save" slot. I can already save anytime I want using the System menu, so what is the quick save slot for?

[image: save menu]

Comment: Well you can “quick save” by pressing “Y” on the first page of the character menu without going into the System Menu, but as for what it’s used for makes little sense to me also

Comment: @Wondercricket You're right, saving on the character menu with Y filled the quick save slot. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick save is another save option in Xenoblade Chronicles 3, and can be done by pressing "Y" on the initial menu without having to gone into the System Menu to do a manual save. Performing a quick save is faster than a manual save (from a user experience perspective, not system perspective), and creates a separate save file without overwriting your manual save.

Based on observations (verification needed), doing the "Continue" option from the title menu will either load the auto-save, quick-save, or manual-save, depending on which one has the latest timestamp, and having a quick saves would serve useful if you have multiple manual saves.